# SailsJS Linkedin OAuth 2.0 Login Flow Issues

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, sails.js, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use this library to authenticate using Linkedin:

https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2

### No Linkedin Login Prompt

I have configured my Passport Linkedin Strategy like so:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
  clientID: 'LINKEDIN_API_KEY',
  clientSecret: 'LINKEDIN_API_SECRET',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/auth/linkedin/callback',
  scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile'],
  state: true
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // asynchronous verification, for effect... 
  process.nextTick(function () {
    // To keep the example simple, the user's LinkedIn profile is returned to 
    // represent the logged-in user. In a typical application, you would want 
    // to associate the LinkedIn account with a user record in your database, 
    // and return that user instead. 
    return done(null, profile);
  });
}));
```

My `AuthController.js` looks like this:

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {

    login: function(req, res) {     
        passport.authenticate('linkedin', function(err, user, info) {
            // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this 
            // function will not be called. 
        });
    },

    callback: function(req, res) {

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // after user authenticated, we get the user's email from
        // Linkedin's JSON response and save it against the matching 　
        // email address in the User model
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        console.log(res);
    },

    logout: function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.send('logout successful');
    }   
};
```

From the linkedin oauth library, I expect the call to:

```
passport.authenticate('linkedin', function...);
```

In my AuthController's login action, to redirect the user to Linkedin's login prompt page but what I am actually seeing is my browser just keeps on loading, loading, loading and never stops.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Some questions I am not sure of:

- Does Linkedin expect my server to be running on HTTPS before it lets this whole thing starts working ?
- Is there some special configurations that I need to do in my Linkedin developers app setting ? (I've enabled all the correct Javascript SDK URLs)

### Callback Error

OK, so continuing on, my next problem appears to be here:

```
return done(null, profile);
           ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

My code is following the npm module instruction here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-linkedin-oauth2

Maybe SailsJS has another way of writing it yet again....

### Authentication Always Fails

After fixing the callback error as mentioned in my solution below, I decided to keep moving on and see how it goes despite the Linkedin documentation isn't quite matching 100% to what I expect from the NPM library.

My next problem is my `authenticated.js` policy appears to always fail.

My code is below:

```
// We use passport to determine if we're authenticated
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.authenticated) { // <---- this is the error line
        return next();
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(401, {
            error: 'Nice try buddy. Try logging in with Linkedin first :]'
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No Login Prompt Solution

*sigh*

I think I'm beginning to grasp some of the difference between SailsJS and pure ExpressJS codes.

The problem appears that I was missing this piece of code at the end of my passport.authenticate() method:

```
(req, res)
```

I picked it up after looking this tutorial again: http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/

So now, the final authenticate method should look like:

```
passport.authenticate('linkedin', function(err, user, info) {



    // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this 
    // function will not be called. 



})(req, res); // <--- notice this extra (req, res) code here
```

Which matches the Passportjs documentation:

```
passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

In a way....if you know what I mean...  :D

Now I got my Linkedin login prompt as expected.

Finally!

### Callback Error Solution

OK.....I'm not sure if this is completes the login process...but....

I noticed I had an extra line:

```
passReqToCallback: true
```

Taken from this page here:

https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/29

I removed that and I got a different error message.

I've also changed my callback code to look like:

```
passport.authenticate('linkedin', function(err, user, info) {

    res.json(200, {
        user: user
    });

})(req, res);
```

and I got my user JSON which appears to be my Linkedin user profile info:

```
{
    user: {
        provider: "linkedin",
        ...
    }
}
```

But that's...contradicting the Linkedin documentation...I don't see any `access_token` or `expire_in` properties which I was expecting to see in step 3 of the Linkedin OAuth 2.0 documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)...

So...supposedly...I should take this user object and create/update against an existing user object ?

### Authentication Always Fails Solution

OK, so few more days, I added extra code to generate a User entity if one isn't found in my database, otherwise just return the found user.

The was one last problem, in my `policies` folder, I have a `authenticated.js` and it looked like this:

```
// We use passport to determine if we're authenticated
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.authenticated) { // <---- this is the error line
        return next();
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(401, {
            error: 'Nice try buddy. Try logging in with Linkedin first :]'
        });
    }
};
```

Being new to all this web development stuff, I thought:

```
req.authenticated; // should call match name of the file ?
```

was correct but I was following this tutorial:

http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/

and he named his file: `isAuthenticated.js` I figured it's just a name....but I was wrong :D

Turns out, the correct code was:

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

So in full, the correct code becomes:

```
// We use passport to determine if we're authenticated
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) { // alright, that's more like it!
        return next();
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(401, {
            error: 'Nice try buddy. Try logging in with Linkedin first :]'
        });
    }
};
```

Perhaps `isAuthenticated` is a Passportjs function and not just a name like I initially thought.

My further research shows this page which suggests so to me:

[Problems getting Passport.js to authenticate user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347896/problems-getting-passport-js-to-authenticate-user)

Maybe `req.authenticated` can only be used for HTML email-password login form as suggested in above Stackoverflow post and `req.isAuthenticated()` is for OAuth stuff.

Anyhow, I still don't know if this is the right path but so far, I got authentication in my application now and I can access protected resources. Not sure how long I'll be logged in for, maybe I still need to build the refresh token thingo every 15 minute like the Linkedin documentation stated ?

Hope this helps other fellow Sailsjs users who are facing the same problem :)

Comment: Hey can you know how to refresh the access token with out user intervention of linkedin

Answer (score 1):

> Does Linkedin expect my server to be running on HTTPS before it lets
>   this whole thing starts working ?

No. The API works just as well on a local http setup.

> Is there some special configurations that I need to do in my Linkedin
>   developers app setting ? (I've enabled all the correct Javascript SDK
>   URLs)

No, your setup is fine.

The browser keeps loading because after the authentication LinkedIn redirects to your callback `action` which isn't handling the response stream.

You need to handle the response in the `callback` action. Something like this will do:

```
callback: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('linkedin', function(err, user){
        // handle error
        // do something with the user (register/login)
        return res.redirect('/home');
    });
}
```

I'd highly recommend using [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) for maintaining third-party logins. Very easy to setup and configure. All you need to do is serve the access tokens and secrets for the different strategies (either through `config/passport.js` or, preferably, through `config/local.js`). Will spare you a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Uh.....no....I am not even seeing a Linkedin login prompt. It has not even got past that stage, it shouldn't call the callback function until it presents the login prompt, the user enters a valid login credentials and accepts the request for access. More to the point, sails-generate-auth is not being actively maintained anymore "OBS: This generator is not currently actively maintained as I simply do not have the time. I'd be more than happy to add willing bodies as collaborators though!"

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to take note of that.